# Struct array in c gives the same value to all values. [C]

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I read words from the file. When I throw them into the structure, it writes the same values.
What is Problem and How can I fix

1. Ide: VsCode
2. Compiler: mingw64-gcc-g++

**File Content;**

```
{Sam} 
{Patrick} 
{Philips}
```

**My Code;**

```
struct Sentence
{
    char *word;
};

struct Sentence *words[20];

void readFile(const char *path, char *fileName)
{
    int wordpointer = 0;
    int len = strlen(fileName);
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen((path), "r")) != NULL)
    {
        char ch = fgetc(fp);
        while (ch != EOF)
        {
            if (ch == '{')
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while (ch != EOF)
                {
                    char word[20];
                    ch = fgetc(fp);
                    if (ch == '}')
                    {
                        //printf("%s\n",word);
                        struct Sentence *st = malloc(sizeof(struct Sentence));
                        st->word = word;
                        words[wordpointer] = st;
                        wordpointer++;
                        break;
                    }
                    word[counter++] = ch;
                }
            }
            ch = fgetc(fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordpointer; i++)
        printf("%s\n", words[i]->word);
}
```

I can get proper output in the printf function in the comment line, but when I print the Struct, all the values ​​as below are the last word in the file.

**Output;**

```
Philips
Philips
Philips
```

Comment: `char ch = fgetc(fp);` should be `int ch = fgetc(fp);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this while loop

```
            while (ch != EOF)
            {
                char word[20];
                //...
```

all pointers st->word = word; points to the same local variable word

```
                if (ch == '}')
                {
                    //printf("%s\n",word);
                    struct Sentence *st = malloc(sizeof(struct Sentence));
                    st->word = word;
                    words[wordpointer] = st;
                    wordpointer++;
                    break;
                }
```

declared like

```
st->word = word;
```

So after exiting the while loop the pointers will be invalid.

You need to allocate memory for each string and copy there entered strings. Moreover you need to append them with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Comment: I append zero character '\0'. but still the same.

Comment: @ResulZoroğlu As I wrote you need to allocate dynamically memory for each string that will pointed to by pointers  st->word

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it by adding  st->word =malloc(sizeof(char));
                                strcpy( st->word, word );

Comment: @ResulZoroğlu You need to write st->word =malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 ); strcpy( st->word, word ); provided that you appended the entered sequence of characters with the terminating zero character '\0'.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, the formulation is good now. I have deleted my comment.